# BigQuery - How to Select new calculated variable?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How can I select a new variable?

Sample:

```
Select case when X=1 then 'Y' 
                     else 'N' end as FLAG,
       case when FLAG='Y' then 1 
                          else 0 end as Y
from [table]
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use same case for 2nd variable also for example

```
Select case when X=1 then 'Y' else 'N' end as FLAG,case when X=1 then '1' else '0' end as Y from [table]
```

Answer (score 0):

As mention by `@Salman ansari`, you can just reuse the case for this new variable if your condition is the same.

But lets put a situation where you still want to have that case column as an actual column, you can use `with`:

```
with case_data as (
Select id,col1,col2,col3,case when X=1 then 'Y' 
                     else 'N' end as FLAG,
from [table]
)
select id,col1,col2,cole,FLAG,case when FLAG='Y' then 1 
                          else 0 end as Y from [case_data]
```

By doing that you can display your case column as a column which can be use on the outer with `select`.

You can explore additional information about `case` and `with` usage on:

- [CASE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conditional_expressions)
- [WITH](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#with_clause)

Comment: In your sample you must read 2 time the same table!

Comment: Actually Im just reading the temp table `case_data` which is the result from the query inside the `with`. Im demostrating the posibility of doing the operation but as `Salman ansari`  points out you can just reuse the condition. Please read about `with` behaviour on the links provided.

Comment: hi Betjens,

Salman's solution is not feasible if the FLAG field is more complex, this is because I am forced to have a redundancy in maintenance.

while in your solution I should read the same table twice and that's exactly what I would like to avoid.

Comment: Another option, as this is for maintenance, is to just fill a new table with all cleaned validations already applied to your table. I think the concept is called `tiers` within your tables. Besides that, I don't think there is a know clause that can behave like what you are looking but you can request such a feature on  [BigQuery issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=1162685).

Comment: To read more about it, you can go to this [link](https://medium.com/codex/delta-lake-architecture-simplifying-data-engineering-analytics-needs-8d8be8459678). ( Only on the part about organizing databases into layers )

Answer (score -1):

I believe there is no solution in BigQuery. but this can be a work-around.

```
Select *,
       case when FLAG='Y' then 1 
                          else 0 end as Y
from (Select *,
     case when X=1 then 'Y' 
                   else 'N' end as FLAG
     from [table])
```